# How to get file ID in google apps scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I am trying to get the ID of the doc that I am working on. Currently I am using

```
var files = DriveApp.getFileById('whatever the doc Id is')
```

and this works fine. However, I want to be able to get any document Id that this application may be running on. I don't want the user to go into the code and switch the ID depending on what document they are on. If anyone has any ideas I would love to hear them,

Thanks

Comment: Furthermore, whats the difference between that line of code and var files = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId(); and why didnt that work for me? That was my solution to the issue. However I've also realized im using the DriveApp so I can use the setDescription method. So I believe I need to use this sort of method. Hopefully someone knows a way around this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Geez I should really have more faith in my guess and check abilities.

```
 var files = DriveApp.getFileById(DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId());
 files.setDescription(des);
```

This works

Answer (score 6):

The id for a file/folder is also in its url. Opening a file you want the id for, your url bar says: `https://docs.google.com/document/d/exampleid1234qwer5678tyui/edit`

The id for that doc will be: `exampleid1234qwer5678tyui`